# How to make Anchor tag show the title without making it clickable

Tags: html, css, anchor, title

So I've created a little help thing using an anchor tag so that when users hover over the "?" they can see a little box with some instructions on it. It works well but when users click on the "?" link it will go to the top of the page. So I am wondering if there is a way to disable that event from happening…

HTML:

```
<a class="questions" href="#" title="instructions are here">?</a>
```

CSS:

```css
.questions:link{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#feb22a;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:100%;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

I've tried to use things like this but it disables the instructions from coming up.

This:

```css
.not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the link to be clickable, why is it a link at all?

Comment: lol because i didnt know how to make a little thing come up when you hover over the "?"

Comment: Nevermind, @j08691 beat me to it :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Link Using CSS but Enable Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892608/disable-link-using-css-but-enable-title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title attribute is a [global attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html) so you can use it on other elements, like a span for example, which won't cause a jump:

```html
<span class="questions" href="#" title="instructions are here">?</span>
```

Comment: hmm let me try this out real quick

Comment: i just did it this way

Answer (score 2):

@jeremy 
hey, you can use jquery to prevent the default action of the anchor tag

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a .questions').on("click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- html code here -->

<a class="questions" href="#" title="instructions are here">?</a>
```

Comment: This is definitely an overkill workaround :P (answers the question itself, but is a bad way to achieve what he wanted). I'd rather go with @j08691's solution

Comment: yes, exactly its better one but he asked for the anchor tag in that case your solution is better. - @marianosimone

Answer (score 1):

In case you aren't already using jquery or don't want to include the jquery library just for this, you can always use plain javascript to prevent the click behavior:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
```

Comment: I will add though that this can be considered "bad practice" but it gets the job done.