# Disable Link Using CSS but Enable Title

Tags: html, css

I want to enable link using CSS but still enable title. Here is my code:

**CSS and HTML Code**:

```css
.disabledLink {
   pointer-events: none;
   opacity: 0.6;
   cursor: default;
 }
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="disableLink" title="My Title" /> 
  <span datahover="test">My Link</span> 
</a>
```

Unfortunately, title is not appearing when hovering my mouse to the link. Is there a better way to enable title?

Comment: do you want title for that link

Comment: what are you trying to achieve because if you simply want to show hover text `title` attribute should be enough....

Comment: **Javascript** - From a comment in a related link... *"Use of `pointer-events: none;` is not perfect. It also disables other events such as hover, which is required for display of title="…" or tooltips. I found the JS solution is better (using `event.preventDefault()`;"*

Comment: If only title is needed then use span tag and add a title attribute to it. Rest of the designs can be attained by CSS also like `<span class="look-like-link" title="My Title">My Link</span>` and `.look-like-link{ text-decoration: underline; color: blue}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```css
.disabled-link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span datahover="test" title="My Title"><a href="www.google.com" class="disabled-link">My Link</a></span>
```

Change your markup into this. It will work. Instead of targeting `<a>` tag, I target the span for title. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your span tag inside the link tag, like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="" title="My Title"> <span datahover="test">My Link</span> </a>
```

Comment: How would this work...since `pointer-events` are disabled for the whole link? And ths is **exactly** what the OP is **already** doing.